# Must declare scalar variable @tablename when updating another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, set, sql-update

I am trying to do:

```
update existingTable
set code = @declaredTable.code
where id = @declaredTable.id
```

but when I do this I get the error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@declaredTable"

twice.

How do I update values of an existing tables to values from a declared tables?

Why doesn't this work?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `JOIN` :

```
UPDATE e 
      SET e.code = d.code
FROM existingTable e INNER JOIN 
     @declaredTable d
     on d.id = e.id;
```

Comment: @MartinSmith. . . For me `@declaredTable` suggests table-variable if so, then the `JOIN` would be needed.